# Visual Studio Cordova project takes decades to load on an android device or crashes

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm running Parallels on my Mac and i'm trying to install an app on my android device. Visual Studio gets stuck at this part here and after around 8min the app starts. Does this happen because i have VS installed on a virtual machine?

**UPDATE:** Visual Studio crashes now after 2min. I have installed the LG G4 drivers, because Windows didn't recognized my device.

> 1>  Running: C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

**EDIT:** Maybe this is also helpful. Before the command above runs, i get this errors:

> Reading build config file: C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json
>       1>  rm: could not remove file (code EBUSY): C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
>       1>
>       1>  rm: could not remove file (code EBUSY): C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
>       1>  rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): C:\GIT\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper
>       1>

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What are your system specifications? Installing an app on your device may take some time, but 8 minutes is just too long.

Comment: I have 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16GB RAM, Paralleles uses 4GB Ram

Comment: @Phonolog I have not very much space left, around 10GB. Could that cause these problems?

Comment: And now VS crashes after 2min.

Comment: Sounds good to me... How many cores can your VM access? The second error looks like your app can't be removed properly. Maybe you can try to deinstall your app manually, before you install it with VS again.

Comment: @Phonolog 4 at the moment

Comment: I had a similar issue. For me, it seems the previous build failed and an application got stuck. I tried to delete the "Platform" directory to force it to refresh the build (which fixes many Cordova build issues) and found the gradle-wrapper.jar was in use. I killed the offending java.exe process, deleted the directory, and then built again. It worked :).